# Sound alarm with Smart Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

I'm working on a project where my iPhone locates a specific item and triggers a sound alarm when needed.

I did my research and found out that this can be done using Smart Bluetooth technology. However, I'm not sure if there's an integrated chip to do the sound alarm function.

Comment: Google "Bluetooth smart nordic" and "Bluetooth smart texas" for two chips. But beware, these are a lot of work. Perhaps look for an Arduino with WiFi to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to develop anything actually. There are devices on the market which already provide the functionality you describe. Have a look at the following two for example:

- The [Treasure Tag](http://www.microsoft.com/en/mobile/accessory/ws-2/) by Nokia, now Microsoft

  - And despite promoting mainly Windows Phones, there's an [iPhone App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/treasure-tag/id836597234?mt=8) for it
- The [StickNFind tags](https://www.sticknfind.com/sticknfind.aspx)

However if you are dead set on developing your own hardware, the common way is to put attach a PWM output to a transistor/fet which drives a buzzer or alternatively there are buzzers which directly generate a noise when you just apply a voltage.

None of the commonly used Bluetooth 4.0 single mode chips are capable of feeding enough current directly to drive a buzzer directly, but on the plus side they pretty much all have PWM outputs.